# Symfony - why generate form is not in Type folder

Tags: forms, symfony, logic

I have a question I ask myself since Symfony 2 and it is still the case on 3.2

When you **use the console to generate formType** of entity :
`doctrine:generate:form`
The EntityType **is in the** *\Form* folder **but not in** *\Form\Type*

Why ?
Sensiolabs itself recommand to put it in the Type folder....

There is a way to adapt this one?

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't recommend that.

As you can see in either [Symfony Doc examples](http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes) or [Symfony Best Practices Guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html), it both use `Form` and not `Type` folder/namespace.

The second one even straightly says:

> **Best Practice**
>
> Put the form type classes in the **AppBundle\Form** namespace, unless you use other custom form classes like data transformers.

Namespace of course, means also path at the same time.

Comment: I remember insight.sensiolabs.com noticed me I should put the FormType in the Type folder (so I changed my habits to let the generate:form and repalce each time the file.
But maybe it is just the algo of sensiolabs that is not "good" ?

With the sentence you quoted, I don't undserstand the "unless" because when you have a web app, in the begin you only have your forms but later in the project you can have the DataTransformers (or other)... so it is not easy to change in the middle of the project.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, best practices recommends creating a sub namespace if other custom form classes are used (like DataTransformer).

For example, i always use :

---Form

-----------DataTransformer

-----------Type

In this case all form classes are stored in Type folder (and namespace).